# Should I test an outgoing command from a private message - ruby

Tags: ruby, tdd

Suppose I have two collaborators, `Sender` and `Receiver`. I would like to unit test `Sender`:

```
class Sender
  attr_accessor :total

  def initialize(receiver)
    @receiver = receiver
    @total = 0
  end

  def calculate
    total += 2
    private_send
  end
private
  def private_send
    receiver.message(self)
  end
end

class Receiver
  ...
  def message(sender)
    sender.total += 5
  end
end
```

I know that I should test the side effects of the incomming command `calculate` e.g

```
sender = Sender.new.calculate
expect(sender.total).to be 7
```

I know that I should also test that outgoing commands are called, but that I shouldn't test private methods.

Should I expect the `receiver` to have been called with `message` in my `Sender` unit test? or is it an implementation detail of `calculate` and is therefore already covered?

Comment: This is largely opinion-based. It's an internal detail of `calculate` as written, and its implementation is already being tested. *How* that end result is reached is arguably irrelevant. Here's the thing: this could also benefit from an integration test since the functionality crosses boundaries, an there's an argument to be made that there's actually a missing class here that handles the implementation details.

Comment: If you have half an hour, this Sandi Metz talk changed the way I approach testing, and specifically answers whether to test incoming / outbound messages

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M

Comment: And if you don't, here's a summary https://gist.github.com/Integralist/7944948

Comment: @Mark thanks for the link. I've seen this previously which is what prompted the question. It's an outgoing command so yes it should be tested that it has been called, but it's also a private implementation detail of `Sender` so it shouldn't, which is where the ambiguity arises from

Comment: It is not fully private implementation detail, because you are passing receiver as an argument to the constructor of Sender. So receiver become a part of public interface of Sender class.